# Binary Makes use of Malloc Function

Tags: ios, flutter, security

This is the vulnerabiltiy after the security analysis of my `flutter apple app`.

The binary may use_malloc function instead of calloc.

This issue is there in the identified `security false positives` in flutter

[Identified security false positives](https://docs.flutter.dev/reference/security-false-positives)

This is a issue of high severity

what should I do to solve this ??

Comment: Ignore the report from the analysis tool.

Comment: @Paulw11 so we just ignore them? There is no way to solve it then?

Comment: Yes, ignore them. Security tools are not infallible. They are often simplistic, just looking for specific function calls that may have problems if not used correctly.  You have linked to the Flutter document that explains why this is a false positive.

Comment: Ok Thankyou @Paulw11.